# std::map with std::pair keys where pair elements has no order importance

Tags: c++, stl

As the question says, I need to use std::map in such way that.

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int*> m;

int* a_ptr = new int;
*a_ptr = 15;
m[std::make_pair(1, 2)] = a_ptr;
std::cout << *m[std::make_pair(2, 1)] << std::endl; //should output 15
```

Now, in my actual implementation all the keys and values are actually pointers. How should I approach this problem?

Two ideas come to my mind.

1. One is I should write a function that every time I am using `m[]` to
   access or to write into map, I should also `m.find()` check the
   other pair combination and act according to that.
2. Other is using std::unordered_map with a custom hasher that
   **somehow makes no difference when `pair`'s elements positions are switched. (I have no idea how to do this, if I multiply or add the
   two pointers the result won't be equal. Need some help if this is
   the way to go.)**

If you can think a better method I will be glad to hear it, otherwise I have stated what I need help with in the second clause. (which I think is more efficient, first one does not look good)

Thanks.

Comment: Wrap the map in a class that sorts the pair elements (so `p.first < p.second`) before using them as a key?

Comment: Why tag this algorithm?

Comment: @Knoothe fixed that.
Yakk, I can't believe I never thought of it.

Comment: @Tolga You can also just XOR the pointers, that operation's commutative and won't overflow. (It might however have terrible hashing behaviour based on the layout of objects in memory.)

Comment: @millimoose this will come in handy in some other situations I can foresee. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you simply ensure the pairs are always in the same order?  Use a helper function, like:

```
std::pair<int,int> my_make_pair(int a, int b) 
{
    if ( a < b ) return std::pair<int,int>(a,b);
    else return std::pair<int,int>(b,a);
}
```

and always use it to access the map:

```
m[my_make_pair(1,2)] = a_ptr;
std::cout << m[my_make_pair(2, 1)] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T, typename PairCmp = std::less<std::pair<T,T>> >
struct symmetric_pair_sort {
  bool operator()( std::pair<T,T> const& left, std::pair<T,T> const& right ) const {
    if (left.second<left.first) {
      return (*this)(std::make_pair( left.second, left.first ), right );
    }
    if (right.second<right.first) {
      return (*this)(left, std::make_pair( right.second, right.first ) );
    }
    return PairCmp()(left, right);
  }
};

// or, the far bulkier yet more efficient:
template<typename T, typename PairCmp = std::less<std::pair<T&, T&>> >
struct symmetric_pair_sort {
  template<bool left_reversed, bool right_reversed>
  bool Helper( std::pair<T,T> const& left, std::pair<T,T> const& right ) const {
    std::pair<T&, T&> left_ordered( left_reversed?left.first:left.second, left_reversed?left.second:left.first );
    std::pair<T&, T&> right_ordered( right_reversed?right.first:right.second, right_reversed?right.second:right.first );
    return PairCmp()( left_ordered, right_ordered );
  }
  bool operator()( std::pair<T,T> const& left, std::pair<T,T> const& right ) const {
    if (left.second<left.first) {
      if (right.second<right.first) {
        return Helper<true, true>(left, right);
      } else {
        return Helper<true, false>(left, right);
      }
    } else {
      if (right.second<right.first) {
        return Helper<false, true>(left, right);
      } else {
        return Helper<false, false>(left, right);
      }
  }
};

std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int*, symmetric_pair_sort<int> > m;
```

Comment: A nice solution. This will come handy in some other scenarios, yet it  will create another pair object if it fails the order, while Nate Hekman's will create one. I don't have too many places that I access to map yet so converting make_pairs to my_make_pairs will be fine now. Otherwise this would be the answer.

Comment: -1 I don't like downvoting answers on questions I have also answered, but I don't like the recursive calls here; it is not obvious that the compiler will be able to remove them. Unfortunately, to use a custom PairCmp, it is necessary to create a new pair, but why not pass it straight to `PairCmp`?

Comment: The 4 fold case looked ugly.  :)  it would be faster, yes.

Comment: I wrote a faster one, where `PairCmp` is expected to take `std::pair<T&, T&>` rather than `std::pair<T,T>.  Much uglier, yet probably faster for non-trivial types: for simple types, I have confidence a compiler could figure out the recursion in the simple case.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a custom comparator

```
[](std::pair<int, int> const& lhs, std::pair<int, int> const& rhs) {
   int lhs_min = std::min(lhs.first, lhs.second);
   int lhs_max = std::max(lhs.first, lhs.second);
   int rhs_min = std::min(rhs.first, rhs.second);
   int rhs_max = std::max(rhs.first, rhs.second);

   return lhs_min < rhs_min || (!(rhs_min < lhs_min) && lhs_max < rhs_max)
}
```

#### How does this work?

The first few lines deterministically order the 2 elements of a pair; that is, you can supply them in either order and `lhs_min` & `lhs_max` will be the same. We then use a standard equivalence technique for the result. All integer copies will be optimised out by the compiler and `min`/`max` will be inlined.

Note that I used C++11's lambdas for convenience of typing and have since discovered that there is no nice way of using them as the comparator for a `std::map`, so you would have to write a functor proper.

Comment: You can't do it like that. `std::map` expects a type as its third template parameter, you're giving it a lambda, which is a value. AFAIK to use a lambda as a comparator here you would've to use `auto cmp = [] ... ; typedef std::map<..., decltype(cmp)> mymap;` but you're still creating a global object no-one uses. Could just use a functor in the first place.

Comment: Also I think that the type you specify must implement function call operator `()`?

Comment: @snipes83 No, lambdas are essentially functors with a funky constructor and `operator()`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use `std::set<int>` instead of `std::pair<int,int>`. Sets store their data ordered, hence there is no need to order your pair, so precisely fulfill your requirement.

On the other hand, the other answers to use a compare wrapper around pair that explicitly orders the pairs might be more practical.

Comment: How so? If I have `set<int> a, b` and insert 1,2 in a and on the opposite order in b, then `a==b` is true.

Comment: Yeah, of course. They have the same contents. However, the `std::set` is an ordered structure; that is, it stores its contents in an ordered way.

Comment: Yes, sure, and precisely because of that, they fulfill the requirement out-of-the-box: these two sets will compare equal, so lookup of {1,2} will also match the key {2,1} (note that mathematically they are simply equal).

Comment: I downvoted as `std::set` is an ordered container, not because they wouldn't compare equal if you inserted them in arbitrary ways (which they don't, they compare equivalent). However, `std::map`s couldn't care less if their keys compared equal or not. All they care about is a strict weak partial ordering, normally provided by `std::less` and `operator<`. It would work, but not for the reason you stated, when apply to C++. (I studied Maths at Uni, I know what a set - in a mathematical sence - is.)

Comment: @Alex: ok, thanks for clarifying, I updated my answer. I was mixing up the mathematical definition of a set and the STL implementation of these. Indeed I overlooked the fact that for implementation sake an ordering has to be present (although that is not relevant for their use here).