# Treat two std::pair(X,Y) same as std::pair(Y,X)

Tags: c++

Here is my code

`typedef std::pair<unsigned long, unsigned long> link;`

```
std::map<link, double> container;
```

What I am trying to do is calculate the distance from X to Y and store in the the container as container.insert(std::make_pair(link, distance));
and say now i have to calculate the distance from Y to X, instead of redoing the whole calculation , fetch the stored value from the container ie.., link and the distance.

My current implementation is only for (X,Y)

```
std::map<link, double>::iterator It = container.begin();
std::pair<unsigned long, unsigned long> k = link(X,Y);
It = container.find(K);
if(It != container.end()) {   distance = It->second; } 
else { /* distance = /* complex calc */ container.insert(std::make_pair(k,distance)); }
```

How can i make it generalized so that link(X,Y) and link(Y,X) be treated as same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your owe make_pair function. This way you can always keep them ordered.

```
typedef std::pair<unsigned long, unsigned long> link;
link make_my_pair(unsigned long x, unsigned long y) {
    if (x < y ) return std::make_pair(x, y);
    return std::make_pair(y, x);
}
```

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15420182/942596).

Comment: thanks a lot! It helped, Instead of returning `std::make_pair(x,y), I returned link(x,y)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a different key comparator for your map, like this one:

```
bool link_compare(link lhs, link rhs) // note: parameters taken by value
{
    if (lhs.first > lhs.second) std::swap(lhs.first,lhs.second);
    if (rhs.first > rhs.second) std::swap(rhs.first,rhs.second);
    return lhs < rhs;
}

std::map<link, double, bool(*)(link,link)> container(link_compare);
```

I think though, that you should consider making `link` a separate class, with data member names specific to it, instead of the generic `first` and `second`.  `std::pair`, in my opinion, is a quick fix for containing unrelated data when you must pass them around as a single object.  What you have is apparently very related data.  Just because `std::pair` happens to be able to hold the right data members, doesn't mean you should use it.

Answer (score 1):

Always keep X and Y sorted, ie. when inserting, searching, deleting, first make the pair sorted, and then use that sorted pair with the map methods.

Alternatively, make your own `link` constructor helper which enforces that rule, and use it directly everywhere you construct them, so that you won't have to convert unnecessarily.

In fact, given that you've defined a specific type, it is good practice to make the type constructor and operators as well, so that if that type changes in the future, you don't have to go through all your code to correct it.